# Foreach loop to iterate over two columns in DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame containing two columns as below:

```
|ColA|ColB|
|A   |1   |
|B   |2   |
|C   |3   |
```

I need to for each loop which will iterate on the basis of two columns.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Asking bluntly for solutions might now work out!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give an example of expected output?